# convert value of TimeOfLastReset to date time

Tags: vb.net-2010, wmi-query, valueconverter

i'm running wmi query to get TimeOfLastReset and i get value like this 20171024080309.437500+420 how can i convert that to the date time

this my code to get TimeOfLastReset in vb.net

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
   Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
   Wscript.Echo "Win32_NetworkAdapter instance"
   Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
   Wscript.Echo "TimeOfLastReset: " & objItem.TimeOfLastReset
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeOfLastReset` property is a [`CIM_DATETIME` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> You can access all Common Information Model (*CIM*) dates and times in
>   `WMI` by using one of two fixed-length formats specific to `WMI` and
>   *CIM*. In scripting, use the [SWbemDateTime object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to convert these to regular dates and times.

---

> The `SWbemDateTime` object is a helper object to parse and set Common
>   Information Model (*CIM*) datetime values.

```
strR = ""                           ' collect results to a string variable  
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48)

' Create a new datetime object.
Set objDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
For Each objItem in colItems
   strR = strR & vbNewLine & "-----------------------------------"
   strR = strR & vbNewLine & "Win32_NetworkAdapter instance"
   strR = strR & vbNewLine ' & "-----------------------------------"

   ' The TimeOfLastReset property is a CIM_DATETIME
   strR = strR & "TimeOfLastReset: " & objItem.TimeOfLastReset
   objDateTime.Value = objItem.TimeOfLastReset

   ' Display the date using the VT_DATE format.
   strR = strR & " local=" & CStr( objDateTime.GetVarDate( True ))
   strR = strR & " UTC="   & CStr( objDateTime.GetVarDate( False))
Next
' the only "echo" allows to run the script using `wscript` or `cscript` host 
Wscript.Echo strR
```

**Output** (truncated):

```
==> cscript //NOLOGO D:\VB_scripts\SO\46903451.vbs

-----------------------------------
Win32_NetworkAdapter instance
TimeOfLastReset: 20171024094043.491317+120 local=24/10/2017 09:40:43 UTC=24/10/2017 07:40:43
-----------------------------------
…
```